# Need to compose email using ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app in Ionic/Cordova for us by iOs and Android smartphone users. As part of the app, I want to compose email in the background. I've researched extensively and found no way to use the standard ngcordova email plugin for this. Can anyone point me to a solution that will facilitate using just one Ionic/Cordova project to build an iOs and an Android app? but i receive error please help me to compose email[I tried with following two URL](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/08/send-email-android-ios-ionicframework/)

[Please help to solve this issue as soon as possible](http://devdactic.com/sending-emails-with-images-in-ionic-cordova/)

Comment: Can you give us more details ? Like the error that you have and the code that you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:`<a href="mailto:user123@gmail.com">user123</a>`

config.xml:`<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="*"/>`

Finally its Working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try [Cordova Email Plugin](https://github.com//cordova-plugin-email-composer/blob/master/README.md). It has pretty much full functionality and you can also send attachments or send formatted HTML in the body. It also has a simple API. And uses the device's native email composer.

You need to wait until the deviceready event fires, but you can use it like so:

```
cordova.plugins.email.open({
    to:          Array, // email addresses for TO field
    cc:          Array, // email addresses for CC field
    bcc:         Array, // email addresses for BCC field
    attachments: Array, // file paths or base64 data streams
    subject:    String, // subject of the email
    body:       String, // email body (for HTML, set isHtml to true)
    isHtml:    Boolean, // indicats if the body is HTML or plain text
}, callback, scope);
```

I find it simpler than the other plugins you seem to be using, and it has good callback hooks too.